# Odd permissions on uploaded files, lamp server

Tags: php, file, permissions, umask

I'm getting odd permissions on files uploaded by php.  I've captured the permissions using fileperms() before and after the move_uploaded_file() call and chmod() call.  The permissions are 33152 before and 334232 after.  I don't even know what these mean.  I'm expecting like 0664 or something.  For info: these numbers in hex and oct:

Dec: 33152 = 0x8180 and o100600, after I chmod(filename, 664) fileperms() gives: Dec: 33432 = 0x8298 and o101230

Super weird permissions. Note the first permissions are coming from the file in the tmp directory before I've moved it.  The file name is something like /tmp/phpc9lNXw

Has anyone ever seen permissions like this on uploaded files?  Where do they come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the permissions in **octal** notation which is **required** -- To do this you need a *leading zero* in front of your permissions set ..

```
chmod(filename, 0664)
```

Comment: Holy crap!  Thanks very much.  I use that command in 3 places, and that one was the only one without the leading 0.  Appreciate it!